# How to migrate WhatsApp messages data from Android to iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, migration, android, whatsapp.app

Currently I'm using an Android phone. I have just purchased a refurbished iPhone 7 Plus. I wish to migrate my WhatsApp chat history from Android phone to iPhone.

I have searched almost everywhere, but couldn't find a genuine Solution to this problem.

Does anyone have any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [WhatsApp's FAQ](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/general/28030001/?category=5245246), please note the emphasized note in the middle:

> ## Changing your phone
>
> ### Different types of phone
>
> If you're moving from one type of phone to another, such as from an iPhone to an Android, and preserving your number, you'll keep your account info. This information is tied to the phone number. Simply download WhatsApp on the new phone and verify your number.
>
> **Note: You can't migrate your messages across different types of phone.**
>
> If you're moving from one type of phone to another and not preserving your number, simply download WhatsApp on the new phone and verify the new phone number.
>
> *Important*: Remember to delete your old account. However, if you didn't delete your account and no longer have access to your old phone, don't worry. If the new owner of your old number activates WhatsApp on a new phone after 45 days, all of your account information tied to that phone number will be completely deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try app like dr.fone https://drfone.wondershare.com/whatsapp-transfer/transfer-whatsapp-messages-from-android-to-iphone.html or AnyTrans https://www.imobie.com/support/transfer-whatsapp-from-android-to-iphone-x.htm